# Set a Visual BEHIND a XAML element's visual

Tags: uwp-xaml

I want to draw something BEHIND a given XAML element. I get its visual via *ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual()* and then add my customly created visual via *ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual()*, but this adds my content at the bottom of the Visual Tree, i.e. ON TOP of the actual elements content. How can I insert something behind it?

e.g.:

```
<Grid x:Name="tst" Width="200" Height="200">
  <TextBlock Text="Test" /> <!-- this will certainly not fill the whole grid -->
</Grid>
```

and in code-behind i'd do

```
var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(tst);
var myBG = visual.Compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
// now do sth fancy with myBG
// ...
// but now this will add myBG IN FRONT OF the XAML element
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(tst, myBG); // but I'd like to have it behind... :(
```

Does anybody have ideas? Thanks :)

edit: and of course I could add a Canvas behind, but in my particular case thats not possible

Comment: "and of course I could add a Canvas behind, but in my particular case thats not possible", that just doesn't sound right to me. This is the only solution to work around the issue, and a valid one since you are using a `Grid` that can host more than one elements.

Comment: hmm, if there's no other way round... probably i shoukd've written "that's not desirable in my case". bzt tganks anyway, just hoped there would be a nicer/simpler solution ;)